# Remove Table data including borders from pdf

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, aspose, aspose.pdf

I have a use case where I want to remove table data from pdf pages. I tried using pdf aspose but it seems `cell.getTextFragments()` is not coming while setting `cellfragment.setText("")`.

Reference Link: https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfjava/Remove+tables+from+existing+PDF

Comment: A little more context would be good.

Comment: Why the PDFBox label?

Comment: Would you please share sample PDF document via Dropbox, Google Drive etc, so that we may investigate and assist you accordingly. **PS**: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.